# Kernel module network device

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to write a Linux kernel module that with the correct command, will bring down the the network interface (lets say wlan0) change its IP address to the one specified, then bring the interface back up. Before the comments begin, yes I know you can use ifconfig, and yes I know you can write user code to do this as well, however for my research project I am trying to learn how to do this in the Linux kernel.

After researching I found the net_device _ops struct which has the methods that I need to call for this (ndo_stop, and ndo_open). However I am struggling to find usage examples and thus tried:

dev->netdev_ops->ndo_stop(dev);

This compiled just fine, however when the module ran, the device was not brought down.

Can anyone provide a proper usage example or let me know what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is the function, should put it here before, better late than never.

```
void targeted(int index, __u32 key){
        unsigned short cur_if;
        struct in_device *in_dev;
        struct in_ifaddr *if_info;
        struct net_device *dev;
        //struct net_device_ops ops;
        __be32 n_key;
        __u32 test2;
        test2 = 0x00FFFFFF;
        //test2 = test2 | key;
        n_key = cpu_to_be32(key);
        cur_if = 0;
        dev = first_net_device(&init_net);
        while (dev && cur_if < IFMAX) {
            in_dev = (struct in_device *)dev->ip_ptr;
            for (if_info = in_dev->ifa_list; if_info != NULL; if_info=if_info->ifa_next){
                    if (cur_if == index){
                        //dev->netdev_ops->ndo_stop(dev);
                        if_info->ifa_address = if_info->ifa_address & test2;
                        if_info->ifa_local = if_info->ifa_local & test2;
                        if_info->ifa_address = if_info->ifa_address | n_key;
                        if_info->ifa_local = if_info->ifa_local | n_key;
                        printk(KERN_DEBUG "New Test::: %pI4", &if_info->ifa_local); //I FOUND IT!!!!!!!
                        //dev->netdev_ops->ndo_open(dev);
                    }   
            }
            cur_if++;
            dev = next_net_device(dev);
        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: How about you check what `ifconfig` does and reproduce that in your code?

Comment: I have and I am trying to reproduce that, problem is I can only see what ifconfig does as user code up until the ioctl() call.

Comment: You can follow the `ioctl` on the kernel side.

Comment: Any suggestion on how best to follow that command?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question ... use the kernel source to follow what the actual `ioctl` does. You don't need to debug it, just look in the code.

Comment: Well the ioctl system calls handle a rather large variety of tasks depending on the parameters. I was just curious if you may have known a particular way to follow the exact ioctl for up/down of an interface. If not no worries.

Comment: Not sure why it's important how many tasks it can do. If you have traced the user side and know exactly what argument it has passed, then surely you can pick the appropriate branch.